# Fix table header inside iframe, when it reaches top

Tags: javascript, html, css

My main page has a div  and an iframe below the div. The div height is of 500px. I am resizing the iframe height, as per its content height. The iframe has a table within. When I scroll down on the main page, and the table reaches the top of the page, I need the header of table, to be fixed, and the table body scrollable. I have tried below code. Have spent around 3 hours on this. Still couldn't get it to work :( .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head></head>
    <body>


    <form id="form_init" onsubmit="return onSubmitHandler();" method="POST" target="iFrame1" action="process.php" name="form_init"></form>
    <div class="content">

        <fieldset>
        <legend><span>Search using Keywords</span></legend>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" onclick="submited=this.id;">

        </fieldset>
    </div>
        <div id="iframeWrapper" style="display: inline;">

            <iframe id="iFrame1" style="display: inline; height: 200px;" name="iFrame1" src="process.php">
               <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <form id="iFrm_search_res" method="" name="iFrm_search_res">
                                <div class="SearchResults">
                                    <table id="searchResultTab" id="innerTable">
                                        <tbody>
                                         <tr class="fix-header">
                                             <th>Header1</th>
                                             <th>Header2</th>
                                             <th>Header3</th>
                                             <th>Header4</th>
                                             <th>Header5</th>

                                         </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td>Row1</td>
                                            <td>Row1</td>
                                            <td>Row1</td>
                                            <td>Row1</td>
                                            <td>Row1</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row2</td>
                                            <td>Row2</td>
                                            <td>Row2</td>
                                            <td>Row2</td>
                                            <td>Row2</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row3</td>
                                            <td>Row3</td>
                                            <td>Row3</td>
                                            <td>Row3</td>
                                            <td>Row3</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row4</td>
                                            <td>Row4</td>
                                            <td>Row4</td>
                                            <td>Row4</td>
                                            <td>Row4</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row5</td>
                                            <td>Row5</td>
                                            <td>Row5</td>
                                            <td>Row5</td>
                                            <td>Row5</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row6</td>
                                            <td>Row6</td>
                                            <td>Row6</td>
                                            <td>Row6</td>
                                            <td>Row6</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row7</td>
                                            <td>Row7</td>
                                            <td>Row7</td>
                                            <td>Row7</td>
                                            <td>Row7</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row8</td>
                                            <td>Row8</td>
                                            <td>Row8</td>
                                            <td>Row8</td>
                                            <td>Row8</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row9</td>
                                            <td>Row9</td>
                                            <td>Row9</td>
                                            <td>Row9</td>
                                            <td>Row9</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row10</td>
                                            <td>Row10</td>
                                            <td>Row10</td>
                                            <td>Row10</td>
                                            <td>Row10</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row11</td>
                                            <td>Row11</td>
                                            <td>Row11</td>
                                            <td>Row11</td>
                                            <td>Row11</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row12</td>
                                            <td>Row12</td>
                                            <td>Row12</td>
                                            <td>Row12</td>
                                            <td>Row12</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row13</td>
                                            <td>Row13</td>
                                            <td>Row13</td>
                                            <td>Row13</td>
                                            <td>Row13</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row14</td>
                                            <td>Row14</td>
                                            <td>Row14</td>
                                            <td>Row14</td>
                                            <td>Row14</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Row15</td>
                                            <td>Row15</td>
                                            <td>Row15</td>
                                            <td>Row15</td>
                                            <td>Row15</td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </body>
                    </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var reached_top = $('#iFrame1').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){  
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > reached_top+5){ 
        $("#iframeWrapper").css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
        $("#iFrame1").contents().find("#fix-header").css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});

    }

    else{
        $("#iframeWrapper").css({'position': 'relative'});
    }

});
```

Please note that the iframe code is generated from another page "process.php". I have copied the code from the browser page source.

Comment: Search around for "Sticky table header"

Comment: I have tried whatever results I got from google. None seems to work. I think, it has something to do with the table being inside the iframe, and generated dynamically.